# How to enable "scroll to click" in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, scrolling

Mac OS X has spoiled me with the ability to scroll to any point I click on a scrollbar.  In Windows XP, I cannot find a native option to enable this same behavior.

For example, if I'm viewing a long webpage (or PDF, etc.) and I click a point on the scrollbar more than one viewport height away, I can scroll directly to that point in a single click under OS X.  In XP, instead it scrolls one page length at a time closer to that point which makes browsing long documents a pain.  I want the "scroll to click" functionality without having to drag the scrollbar.

I have gone through the appropriate control panels and Tweak UI app of Powertoys to no avail.

I do not have any 3rd-party mouse software installed.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hold `shift`, then click on that point in the scrollbar.  It will take you there directly.

Comment: Damn, 8 seconds away from answering my first Windows question. :P Upvoted!

Comment: Sorry!  You can take the next one :)

Comment: I should clarify: I want this to be the default behavior when I click on on a scrollbar.  Is there a Registry setting or app that allows this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, and I can't find any through searching.  There probably is going to be a program to mac-like behavior, but I doubt you can get one that only affects scrollbars.

Comment: That would be fine.  I'll leave this open for a bit in case one turns up.

Comment: In some scroll bars, you can right click and select "Scroll Here". Not exactly what you want, but might be easier than reaching for the Shift key in some cases.