# Middle-click on Windows' scroll bars

Tags: windows, scrolling

I'm a spoiled KDE brat who must work with Windows a bit. Kwin, the KDE window manager, allows one to middle-click on any scrollbar in any application and the window will scroll to that location. I found a SU answer that describes how to [Ctrl-click to scroll to position](https://superuser.com/a/171444/93684) however is there any way to configure a middle-click for the same function? Note also that the Ctrl-Click does not work in Firefox.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just click on that location? Instead of adding a modifier?

Comment: @Tom: I suppose that you mean to Ctrl-Click that location. No, I have difficulty using the keyboard and the mouse at the same time. I prefer to mostly stick with the Keyboard, in KDE with Vimperator this is easy, but Windows seems to be very mouse-dependent. Using both at the same time is just abut out of the question.

Comment: **No, just click on the location.** No Ctrl, no keyboard, no middle, no magic; just ***click***...

Comment: Tom, I could repeatedly click on that location to get the scrollbar there eventually, but that might require tens of clicks on a very long document. I am looking to get there in a single click, like KDE offers.

Comment: Try middlemouse.scrollbarPosition in Firefox (about:config)

Comment: Not a spoiled brat. Just someone used to getting their key bindings the way they want them to, instead of each individual app telling you what to do.

Answer (score 3):

(I know this is an older question but wanted to share anyway since it was unanswered.)

This can be done with Firefox. I'll update this answer soon as I test settings in other browsers:

### In Firefox (tested with v27.0)

- In the address bar, type `about:config` and hit enter:

[image: the about config window]

- In the search box, type `middle` to filter the search options:

[image: typing in the search box filters the search]

- You'll see an option called `middlemouse.scrollbarPosition` -- note that it defaults to false:

[image: the middlemouse.scrollbarPosition option]

- Right-click on the option and select `Toggle`, or double-click it:

[image: toggling the option]

- The option will now read `true` and `User set`:

[image: the option toggled to true]

- Restart Firefox and it should work as expected. I tested with a T650 touchpad.

Comment: Thank you. Firefox is the least of problems, with plugins such as [Tridactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tridactyl-vim/). When I'm in Windows I usually need the functionality in whatever random PDF view is installed, MS Office, and other native Windows apps.