# Tweak Windows 10 scrollbar to jump to clicked location by default

Tags: windows, windows-registry, autohotkey, scrolling, desktop-customization

In Windows 10 (and probably all other Windows versions too), clicking a scrollbar above or below its handle scrolls up or down by one page. But instead, I'd like to jump to the clicked location. [There is already a functionality for that](https://superuser.com/a/171444/652023), which is triggered by either using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> or (in some applications) right clicking and choosing "scroll here" from the context menu. But I want that functionality to be the default behavior.

How can I make "scroll here" the default action for left clicks in scrollbars?

Ideally, there would be a registry setting or something like that. But I'm also open to hacks like an AutoHotKey script that detects left clicks on scrollbars and injects a <kbd>Shift</kbd> for these clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this AutoHotkey script:

```
~LButton Up::
    ; Get the current position of the mouse cursor:
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY, A ; A means the active window
    ; Get the position and size of the active window:   
    WinGetPos, WinX, WinY, WinWidth, WinHeight, A
    If (MouseX > (WinWidth - 20) and MouseX < WinWidth and MouseY > 200) ; right edge 
        SendInput, +{Click} ; + is the symbol for Shift
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me. Letting the original click pass through (`Up` and `~` modifier) and sending another Shift+Click afterwards was problematic, as the Shift+Click was ignored 40% of the time in some applications. Also, `MouseY > 200` was a bit high. I [found a way to fix those](https://superuser.com/a/1691378/652023) and other finer details. However, there are still some issues left, for instance dragging the scroll handle.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaption of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1691136/652023) with some bugfixes and a filter such that the script only activates in predefined applications.

There is still room for improvement. For instance, you cannot drag the scroll handle anymore.

#### AutoHotkeyScript

```ahk
#NoEnv
#Warn All

#If MouseIsOverScrollbar("firefox|chrome|notepad|hh")
LButton::
    ; "+" is the modifier for shift
    SendInput, +{Click}
return
#If

MouseIsOverScrollbar(Exe_Regex) {
    if (A_Cursor != "Arrow")
        return False

    MouseGetPos, _X, _Y, WindowUnderMouse

    WinGet, Exe, ProcessName, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
    if (not Exe ~= "^(" . Exe_Regex . ")\.exe")
        return False

    WinActivate, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    WinGetPos, _X, _Y, WinWidth, _H, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
    ScrollbarWidth = 25
    HeaderWidth = 40
    return MouseX > WinWidth - ScrollbarWidth
       and MouseY > HeaderWidth
}
```

For AutoHotKey 2 you might want to switch to `CoordMode, Mouse, Client` and `WinGetClientPos`.

For debugging I found `SoundPlay *-1` to be helpful whenever a Shift+Click is inserted.